# Created a procedure for merging two tables branch_mstr and new_branches (having only two fields and same primary key)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, datatables, merging-data

```
delimiter $$
create procedure mergeData()
begin
    declare counter, rowws int default 0;
    set rowws = (select count(*) from new_branches);
    begin
        while counter < rowws do
            if new_branches.branch_no != branch_mstr.branch_no then
            insert into branch_mstr value(new_branches.branch_no, new_branches.name);
        end while;
        end;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

[Why these crosses are showing, I am using MySQL and new to the PL/SQL. Asking for the help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGRbz.png)

Comment: You are missing an end if; and valueS not value and you do have to read new_branches at some point, You seem to be confusing procedures with triggers, and you don't need a loop and you don't need a procedure...

Comment: AND you don't increment counter so you have an infinite loop..You should step back, review and post a credible attempt if you get into difficulty.